# How do I compare two similar dates within a container using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, compare, each

How do I compare two similar dates within a container?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="itemHead">
        <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
        <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHead">
        <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 02, 2017</span>
        <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHead">
        <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
        <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to use each() to traverse inside the container

```
$(".itemHead").each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".ModuleDate").length==0){
        //How shall I compare two dates?
    }
})
```

Comment: A little unclear... Do you want to "detect" if there is duplicates? What is the result you expect if there is?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  Yes, actually I want to detect it, if there were any duplicates. My end result would be like "Mar 01, 2017 is repeated twice". Sorry, if I wasn't more specific about my question earlier.

Comment: I improved my answer to obtain the desired end result format. ;) Have a look!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That was so kind of you. Exactly, what I wanted to see. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Then, please mark the answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-------- 2nd EDIT**

I just made a shorter code to do exactly the same thing as the previous edit.
But, this time, using an object to store counts.
This one should be final!!!
;)

```js
// =============================================== Create an array to loop throught
var date_array=[];
$(".itemHead").each(function(){
  date_array.push(  $(this).find(".ModuleDate").text() );
})
//console.log( JSON.stringify(date_array));

// =============================================== Count occurances and store results in an object
var count_obj = {};
for (i=0;i<date_array.length;i++) {
   count_obj[date_array[i]] = (count_obj[date_array[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
//console.log( JSON.stringify(count_obj));

// =============================================== Show result when count is greater than 1
$.each(count_obj, function(index, value) {
  if(value>1){
    console.log(index + " is repeated " + value + " times.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 02, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 04, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 05, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 06, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**-------- 1st EDIT**

Okay, you want to have the results shown as a count for each duplicated dates.
I added another loop to count occurances and a final loop to format results as readable strings.

```js
var date_array=[];

var compared_indexes=[];
var duplicate_indexes=[];

// =============================================== Create an array to loop throught
$(".itemHead").each(function(){
  date_array.push(  $(this).find(".ModuleDate").text() );
})

//console.log( JSON.stringify(date_array));

for(i=0;i<date_array.length;i++){       // Loop throught each dates
  for(j=i+1;j<date_array.length;j++){   // to compare it with all others

    if( ( date_array[j] == date_array[i] ) && ( $.inArray(j,duplicate_indexes)==-1 )  ){ // Match!

      // log the compared index
      compared_indexes.push(i);

      // log the duplicate index
      duplicate_indexes.push(j);

      //console.log( "date_array["+j+"] is a duplicate of date_array["+i+"]." );
    }
  }
}

//console.log( JSON.stringify(compared_indexes));
//console.log( JSON.stringify(duplicate_indexes));

// =============================================== Now count the duplicate occurances
var hit_array=[];
var count_array=[];
var count_index=0;
var prev;

for (i = 0;i<compared_indexes.length;i++) {
  if ( compared_indexes[i] !== prev ) {
    
    hit_array.push(date_array[compared_indexes[i]]);
    count_array[i]=2;
    count_index=i;
  }else{
    count_array[count_index] = count_array[count_index]+1;
  }
  prev = compared_indexes[i];
}

//console.log( JSON.stringify(hit_array));
//console.log( JSON.stringify(count_array));

// =============================================== RESULTS

for(i=0;i<hit_array.length;i++){
  console.log(hit_array[i] + " is repeated " + count_array[i] + " times.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 02, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 04, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 05, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 06, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="itemHead">
    <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 03, 2017</span>
    <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**FIRST ANSWER**

I'm not sure that is what you expect...

But it may put you on tracks.
It detects duplicate dates and logs both dates indexes when a match is found.

```js
var date_array=[];

var compared_indexes=[];
var duplicate_indexes=[];

// Create an array to loop throught
$(".itemHead").each(function(){
  date_array.push(  $(this).find(".ModuleDate").text() );
})

console.log( JSON.stringify(date_array));

for(i=0;i<date_array.length;i++){       // Loop throught each dates
  for(j=i+1;j<date_array.length;j++){   // to compare it with all others
  
    if( date_array[j] == date_array[i] ){ // Match!
      
      // log the compared index
      compared_indexes.push(i);
      
      // log the duplicate index
      duplicate_indexes.push(j);
      
      console.log( "date_array["+j+"] is a duplicate of date_array["+i+"]." );
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="itemHead">
        <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
        <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHead">
        <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 02, 2017</span>
        <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHead">
        <span class="ModuleDate">Mar 01, 2017</span>
        <a href="#" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```